# Capture Facebook share/post to FB event

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on one of my pet projects. Where one of the features I need is as follows:

1. User clicks the “share to Facebook” button on my web page, as done here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
2. And then in Facebook popup window, user can either click “post/submit” or cancel or close the window. Is there any way to know that user did really post to his/her Facebook timeline?
3. Please assume, that user is not my friend or have never liked my page, but user is currently logged in to Facebook in another browser tab.
4. I see FB events, those can be captured in callback at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ , e.g. edge.create can capture like button.

Similarly is there any way to capture “share/post to fb” ?

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe that you can do this with the share button.

You can however, initiate the same dialog using the JavaScript SDK. Using the SDK, you'll be able to capture the callback function that you mentioned.

Here is the example given in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/):

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Lix doesn't work anymore. The UI methods have changed, now this would be the Share Dialog (not Feed), which only returns the post object if "the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

As far as I've found, there's no event to subscribe to for post sharing.